# Вызов методов сервлета из браузера

Tags: java

задали вопрос и не знаю 100%-го ответа: можно ли из браузерной строки напрямую вызвать метод сервлета? 
Насколько я понимаю, физически это невозможно. Поправьте, пожалуйста, если не прав.

Comment: Почему это нельзя, а doGet(), doPost()

Comment: Если вам нужно проверить работоспособность сервлетов, то можете скачать приложение "PostMan" и там вы сможете выбрать нужный метод запроса, а также указать необходимые параметры для него...

Answer (score 0):

Если это `doGet`, то достаточно вбить в адресную строку URL, на который он замаплен.

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую нельзя, только после того как управление будет передано сервлету. Если в URL добавить название метода, который надо вызвать то тогда, метод можно получить из URL и вызывать из сервлета с помощью рефлекшена.